# Add contour plot on top of an image in GNU Octave

Tags: plot, octave, contour

I have some Matlab code that I would like to be able to run in Octave, but for some reason I cannot seem to get the contour for an image segmentation algorithm to plot on top of the image. I would like to do the following:

```
I = peaks(100);
figure(1);
imagesc(I);
hold on;
contour(I, [0 0], '-r', 'linewidth', 3)
hold off;
```

This works for me in MATLAB, but not in Octave.

Comment: Please show us the plot in both interpreters so that we can see the differences. This is what I've got on GNU Octave: http://i.imgur.com/IVprg4s.png

Comment: Also works on Octave 4.0.0, Ubuntu 16.04. https://imgur.com/a/d9pskss

Answer (score 1):

Just like with juliohm, your code works perfectly fine for me with Octave Version 3.8.2 under Linux. You probably only have to update your octave version. Otherwise, perhaps post your question to the octave help list: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/help-octave